# Running a service

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, service

I have a service that exports a file to a location on the server, however I need this service to be able to copy the file to another domain as well as the current one. I have attempted to run the service using admin rights but that will not work as the system admin is on domain1/admin and this does not have access to domain2 same as domain2/admin does not have access to domain1. Is it possible to skip the log on part of a service?

Answer (score 4):

No - the way I see it, there are only a few ways around this:

1. Enable a trust between your two domains, so that DOMAIN1\User has rights to copy a file to DOMAIN2's server
2. Write the service so that it can *internally* authenticate with DOMAIN2's file share using DOMAIN2\User
3. The only other way I could think of would be to map a network drive in the context DOMAIN1\User, to the DOMAIN2 file sharer using DOMAIN2\User credentials. Then, run the service in the context of DOMAIN1\User. To be honest, I don't know if this will work
4. If possible, use a scheduled task instead of a service. You could definitely do (3) using  a batch file, then
5. **NOT RECOMMENDED** - Allow anonymous access to the file share. Please don't do this, it's just here for completeness

Answer (score 2):

No, your service has to run under SOME security context.  You'll need to run it as a user that has access to resources on both domains, making sure that the proper trusts exist between the domains.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to use an account that has permission in both domains. Assuming you have a trust of some sort between the two, you're going to want to grant the service account running your service the appropriate rights on the servers in each domain.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a trust?

Comment: Re-write your service to authenticate using alternate credentials for each domain and rely on your app for the authentication and not the account running the service.